# Angular 2 method for querySelectorAll and className

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to know the best way to define functions to get all elements of a list and apply/remove a class style to all of it.

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".example > li");

x.className = "";
```

How to angularize 2 the above? Can anyone help with an example?

Comment: You should use NgClass.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but in this case I need to do it in my controller. :(

Comment: Why do you need to do it in the controller? Fundamentally, modifying the document rather than supplying input data to the document is directly counter to Angular's design principles.

Comment: Angular2, and indeed TypeScript, is just JavaScript at the end of the day. Have you tried just using the code you have above?

Comment: Yes, but I would like to know how to do it using the best practices in Angular 2. Is it possible? Thank you!

Comment: No, that's not the "best" way; it won't even work, because `querySelectorAll` returns a **list** of nodes, which you will have to loop over to assign or remove the class (which you should do using the `classList` interface by the way). Anyway, Angular does not extend the DOM interfaces or provide any features that would do what you want (other than using conditional classes in templates, as mentioned in comments and answers).

Answer (score -1):

Angular 2 best practices are that the document as written in the templates is the document that gets shown to the user. Full stop. The document can have conditional elements that may change their appearance, content, and even existence depending on data provided by the controller, but those are still defined *in the document*.

To implement this by Angular 2 best practices, you must specify *in the document template* that each list item has whatever class you're concerned with, conditional on some variable or expression that uses values provided by the controller. NgClass is the usual way to do this. Then the controller updates that variable, and lets Angular change detection figure out all the classes that need to update in response.

Comment: I am doing this in my controller because I am applying a fade effect by hand  every 1000ms. I know it's not the best way to do it, but hey, everything is possible, right? I want to know how to do it in my controller using the possibilities Angular 2 gives us.

Comment: @Eustace The fade effect every 1000ms sounds very much like something you could do with CSS animation. If this is your use case, it would be useful to edit your question to mention that.

Comment: @Eusthace Angular 2 simply does not support what you are trying to do in the way you are trying to do it, because it fundamentally violates Angular 2's basic design principles. To accomplish the goal of "apply a fade effect every 1000ms", apply the fade effect in the document conditional on a controller variable, and trigger it by changing the variable's value.

Comment: I don't know the number of elements in my list (maybe 1, maybe 1000) and I need to rotate the list with a fade effect to show every item in the list using a fade effect. Let say I can't do this using css/views. How to do it in my controller?

Comment: @Eusthace You'll have to be more detailed about what you're trying to do. Are you showing one item at a time, and having it fade out and then fade back in as the next item once per second?